# Notificacion Push de sonido reproduciendose

Tags: ionic, angular, notificaciones

he hecho una aplicacion y esta reproduce un una radio online, pero cuando le doy play, esta no muestra como una notificacion de que algo se esta reproduciendo.. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Aldo. Si no muestras parte del código donde creas que pueda estar el problema es muy complicado que alguien pueda orientarte. Te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve].

Comment: No se si viste lo que pregunte, estoy consultando como puedo hacer una notificacion cuando la radio se esta rproduciendo en la parte donde muestran las notificaciones como hace youtube.

Comment: Supongo que ya lo habrás mirado pero ¿has configurado los privilegios de tu aplicación en tu móvil?. Sobre todo la parte de la permisión de notificaciones para la app.

Comment: No, esto que me permitiria?

Comment: Te permitiría ver en la barra de notificaciones que se está ejecutando un proceso de tu app. Pero creo que no te estoy entendiendo entonces.

Comment: exactamente! Eso es lo que estoy buscando